# Some one can explain why return its not back?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I tried this code work, but I can understand what's happened.

```
save: function(req, res){
    // Recoger los parametros de la peticion
    var params = req.body;

    // Validar los datos
    var validate_name = !validator.isEmpty(params.name);
    var validate_surname = !validator.isEmpty(params.surname);;
    var validate_email = !validator.isEmpty(params.email) && validator.isEmail(params.email);       
    var validate_password = !validator.isEmpty(params.password);


    if(validate_name && validate_surname && validate_email &&validate_password){
        console.log('Validado');
        // Crear Objeto de usuario
        var user = new User();

        // Asignar valores al usuario
        user.name = params.name;
        user.surname = params.surname;
        user.email = params.email.toLowerCase();
        user.role = 'ROLE_USER';
        user.image = null;

        user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(params.password,10);


        //Comprobar si el usuario existe 
        User.findOne({email: user.email}, (err, issetUser) => {
            if(err){
                return res.status(400).send({
                    'message': "Registro de usuario fallido por duplicidad 1"
                });
            }else{
                console.log('Estoy por aca');                                   
                if(!issetUser){       
                    console.log('Estoy por aca2'); 
                    //Guardar el usuario
                    user.save((err, userStored)=>{
                        if(err){
                            return res.status(500).send({
                                'message': "No se pudo grabar el usuario"
                            });
                        } else{
                            if(!userStored){
                                return res.status(500).send({
                                    'message': "No se pudo grabar el usuario"
                                });
                            } else{
                                // Devolver respuesta                        
                                return res.status(500).send({'message': "Registro de usuario exitoso" });
                            }}
                    });
                    console.log('No deberia estar aca');
                }else{  
                    console.log('El usuario esta registrado en la DB');                   
                    return res.status(500).send({
                        'message': "Registro de usuario fallido 3"
                    });
                }
            }   
        });
    }else{
        return res.status(500).send({'message': "El usuario existe en la DB 5"});
    }   
    return res.status(500).send({'message': "Registro de usuario fallido 6" });          
}
```

for example, I send (by postman) a register than exist in the database. So I expect show in the console: El usuario esta registrado en la DB and return "Registro de usuario fallido 3", but, by console show:

> Validado
>   Estoy por aca
>   El usuario esta registrado en la DB

and crash with message:

> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

In postman return: "message": "Registro de usuario fallido 6"
So, how the program, continues at the end if i put a return before ?!
why the program crash ?

thank you and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

The crash happens because you are calling res.send() twice.

The last line of your code:

```
return res.status(500).send({'message': "Registro de usuario fallido 6" });
```

is executed irrespective of the response from mongo.

This is why you get the message "Registro de usuario fallido 6" in postman.

Post that you mongoose request returns with the existing user and you try to call res.send again.

Comment the last line and your code should work fine.